# "Отправить на миссию". Можно ли так написать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Подвох в том, что их отправляют ***на*** (?) миссию, где они, вероятнее всего, погибнут".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Подвох в том, что их **отправляют на  миссию**, где они, вероятнее всего, погибнут".

Думаю,  что это **стилистическая ошибка:**  "послать на миссию" нельзя, так как это только **добровольное** выполнение человеком ответственной задачи в высоком (или ироническом) смысле.

**Пример:**

В обращении с ними он становился особенно учтив и покладист и мягко, деликатно, без шуму **выполнял свою многотрудную миссию**. [К. И. Чуковский. Короленко в кругу друзей (1940-1969)]

**МИССИЯ**, 1. кого-чего или с опр. Предназначение к чему-л. **важному, ответственная роль** кого-, чего-л. М. поэта. Высокая м. искусства.

Answer (score 1):

Да, этот предлог вполне сочетаем со словом "миссия". Как "отправить на задание". А вот "в миссию" уже нельзя.